# Aggregating queries by maximum count (MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a follow table like so:

```
id eventid user
1   1       ABC
2   4       XYZ
3   4       DEF
4   1       XYZ
5   1       DEF
```

And an event table like so:

```
eventid  title  desc 
 1       tuv    Lorem Ipsum
 2       yfc    Lorem Ipsum
 3       jhk    Lorem Ipsum
 4       lmn    Lorem Ipsum
```

I want a query that would output the list of popular events based ordered by the highest number of followers of that event.
For ecample, eventid 1 has the highest number of followers so that will be listed first and second will be event with eventid=4

Comment: this a basic sql query using join,count,group by and order by before posting first give it a try by your self

Comment: Tried and failed. That's why posted here. Especially since I have a lot of work on my mind and coping up with deadlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select t1.eventid,t1.count(t1.eventid) as count_followers  
 from table_name t1 inner join events_table t2 
 on t1.eventid=t2.eventid group by t1.eventid order by count_followers desc
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked seamlessly